# Javascript unescape equivalent in golang?

Tags: javascript, go

Is there an equivalent of JavaScript's `unescape()` in Golang?

JavaScript example:

```
<script>
var c = unescape('%u0107');     // "ć"
console.log(c);
</script>
```

Comment: Do none of https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=urldecode do the trick? Or failing that, does the approach explained over on https://www.urldecoder.io/golang work? (I don't know anything about Go, but searching for "urldecode in go" seems to give a number of usable solutions already?)

Comment: The Go standard library does not have an equivalent to the deprecated `unescape` function in Javascript.  The Go standard library does have functions for unescaping URL % encoding (see [url functions](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#pkg-functions)).

Comment: No those do not produce the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unescape` function is marked as "Deprecated" (red trash can), in the Mozilla documentation [1]. As such, I wouldn't recommend using it, and certainly not seeking out an equivalent Go function. Go has a similar function [2], but it expects different input from what you have provided:

```
package main
import "net/url"

func main() {
   s, err := url.PathUnescape("%C4%87")
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   println(s == "ć")
}
```

If you are really set on doing this, you could see about translating this
polyfill [3].

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape
2. https://godocs.io/net/url#PathUnescape
3. https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.unescape.js